# How do I keep my shower handle's entire stem from spinning?

Tags: shower

I unscrewed the knob and pulled it off, then took of the escutcheon, then removed the entire valve body.
The stem screws in and out of the valve body which is what controls the water flow.
The valve body is smooth and has a rubber o-ring at the end of it.
My question is what holds the valve body in the seat?
The body just keeps spinning when I turn the handle.
I read this on another forum which sounds similar to my problem:

"the hold down retaining nut that you remove that secures the stem in the body needs to be very tight so the barrel seat will not move. some of the barrels have an "O" Ring seal at the base and can cause the barrel to slip, so tighten it down real good. Let me know if that helps...."

I did make the nut pretty tight, but it still spins.
Any other ideas?

Comment: It's hard to understand your question. You could make it clearer by adding (1) what is the exact problem you're experiencing -- does the water get too hot or too cold or does it leak or what? and (2) what is the brand and type of your valve (e.g. Symmons Temptrol II). Pictures never hurt, too.

Comment: Sorry about that, the problem is that the water doesn't shut off completely. It leaks. When you turn try to turn off the water, the handle just keeps spinning, it doesn't stop like it should.

Comment: Not too sure about the brand. I was told it is a Kohler, but can't verify. I would have taken some pictures, but the wife has the camera and won't be back for a while.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your dilemma as I understand it, is answered [Here](http://www.ehow.com/video_8443468_tighten-stop-leaking-shower-head.html).